# Where are ArrayUtils.insert() methods in version 3.12.0

Tags: eclipse, apache-commons

I cannot get Spring Framework ArrayUtils.insert() methods to show in Eclipse. The pom.xml has the 3.12.0 version of org.apache.commons.lang3.  I can see the methods under Maven Dependencies.  However, in the editor, I cannot get to any of the ArrayUtils.insert() methods.  Why would that be?

I tried using org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils and I was able to see the add() methods but not the addFirst() methods.

Are they dependent on Java version or something?   The methods are there plain as day in the Maven Dependencies.  But, they're compile errors (not found) when I try to use them.

Comment: What do you see instead? What can you show us?

Comment: When I'm coding, and hit ctrl-enter, I can see available methods as usual.  But, for ArrayUtils, after the .indexOf() methods it jumps to isEmpty().  There are no .insert() methods.  I've double-checked all the dependencies that I don't have a much older lang3 library overriding the the 3.12.0 version.  Can't explain why.  Have never seen this situation on anything Java.